# Any tutorial for FIFA 12 Goalkeeper Pro?

Tags: fifa-12

I played as goalkeeper in FIFA 12 and I'm not really sure how to control him. Does anyone know of any good resources on how to play as goalkeeper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is done by what it sounds like a 10 year old but I found this for you, give it a watch: